# VBA Pivot Table not being created, and I don't know why

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to make a pivot table using a macro sub, but my code isn't working at full. The worksheet is created and named, but it stays empty. I've tried changing the data range, as seen on another similar question I found here, but it didn't work. I'm trying to make "shape-button" that creates a pivot table of a large amount of data. There's some time since I've worked with VBA, so excuse my noob questions and poor coding.
Any help is appreciated!

Here's the code:

```
Sub InsertPivotTable()

'Declare Variables
Dim PSheet As Worksheet 'nova planilha pra tab dinamica
Dim DSheet As Worksheet 'planilha de dados da tab dinamica
Dim PCache As PivotCache 'nome do cache
Dim PTable As PivotTable 'nome pra tab dinamica
Dim PRange As Range 'tamanho da fonte de dados
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

'Insert a New Blank Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("TESTE TabDin").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "TESTE TabDin"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set PSheet = Worksheets("TESTE TabDin")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("GESTÃO ORDENS ESMAGAMENTO")

'Define Data Range

LastRow = DSheet.Cells(DSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(16, DSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(16, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

'Define Pivot Cache

Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
     CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), TableName:="TBAutom")

'Insert Blank Pivot Table

Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="TBAutom")

'Insert Row Fields

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TBAutom").PivotFields("CLASSE")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TBAutom").PivotFields("CENTRO TRAB.")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 2
End With

'Insert Column Fields

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TBAutom").PivotFields("SETOR")
.Orientation = xlColumnField
.Position = 1
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TBAutom").PivotFields("REVISÃO")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 2
End With

'Insert Data Field

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TBAutom").PivotFields("TIPO")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 1
.Function = xlCount
.NumberFormat = "###"
.Name = "CONTAGEM DE ORDENS"
End With

'Format Pivot

TableActiveSheet.PivotTables("TBAutom").ShowTableStyleRowStripes = _
       TrueActiveSheet.PivotTables("TBAutom").TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium9"

End Sub
```

Comment: Get rid of the `On Error Resume Next`, rerun, and report back on the error message and the line that throws it.

Comment: Remove the CreatePivotTable from the end of your `Set PCache = `  line   That is setting PCache to a pivot table object, not a pivot cache.  But also remove the `On Error Resume Next`